# request not entering into the controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have been trying this from long time but not getting what is the mistake that i am doing,
here is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 puts "before"
 def create
  puts  "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
  puts params
  User.create(:birthday=> params["dateOfBirth"],:email=> params["emailId"])
 end
 puts "after"
end
```

and here is my routes
post '/sign_up', :to => "users#create"

this is giving me a 200 OK response code but not actually entering into the method "create" and storing the values in databse
it is priting "before" and "after" but not "hiiiiii"
looks like i am doing some silly mistake but need help to get it done
thanks.!

This is how i am doing query from client side.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  }
});

var registration = function(){
  var user = {
   firstname   : $("#firstname").val(),
   lastname    : $("#lastname").val(),
   emailId     : $("#email").val(),
   password    : $("#psw").val(),
   dateOfBirth : $("#birthday").val() };   
  $.post("/sign_up", user, function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },'json');
```

};

Comment: show the relevant section of your log please.

Comment: Make sure any `before_filter` is not halting your request.

Answer (score 0):

For really good debug pupposes use gem [rails-pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails). Add gem 'pry-rails' to your gemfile, run 'bundle install'. Now you can add 'binding.pry' to any place of your code, and when your app reach this line you will have a full access to this code from console. It's better than use 'puts'. 
For your  In you case it would be:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  puts "before"
  def create
    binding.pry
    User.create(:birthday=> params["dateOfBirth"],:email=> params["emailId"])
  end
  puts "after"
end
```

Run application, open your browser and go to url. Than open console and you will be 'inside' create action

**UPDATE**
Look at my example, I've created it and all works good

Model: User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :email, :gender, :name
end
```

Controller: UsersController.rb

```
def create
    binding.pry
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    session[:user] = @user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

users.js:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    }
  });

  var registration = function(){
    alert('a');
    var user = {
     name   : $("#name").val(),
     city   : $("#city").val(),
     gender : $("#gender").val()
    };
    $.post("/sign_up", user, function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },'json');
  }

  $('#but').click(registration);
});
```

new.html.erb:

```
<form>
  <input id="name">
  <input id="city">
</form>
<button id="but">create</but>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :users
post '/sign_up', :to => "users#create"
root :to => 'users#new'
```

I run application, fill form, open console -> I'm in create action

Comment: thanks, its really nice. but that doesn't solve my problem neither it tells why its happening.

Comment: In your routes.rb post action points to 'create' action. So show us how do you send this query. It is form or jQuery or smth else?

Comment: thanks @Birlin, i have copy-pasted your code. and it is now going inside the create action. but javascript is giving error on click of button saying registration not defined.

Comment: and also i still didn't get that what was the issue with my earlier code.and what is that $(function(){.....}) syntax i am new to jquery it will be better if you point me any article which axplains that (except jquery doc).

Comment: $() - means that code in brackets is evaluated after all page is loaded. Inside this brackets I wrote anonymous function to execute. This function has you code - Ajax settings and registration function.  In last line of code I bind registration function to onclick event of button. If you have 'registration undefined' check you function name and all brackets